# How to calculate where 2 measures are equal in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is my table
table

```
CLIENT   DATE    TOTSALE    EQPSALE
A        Jan     15.00      15.00
A        Feb     25.00      25.00
B        Jan     10.00      0
C        Feb     12.00      6.00
B        Feb     11.00      11.00
A        Mar     5.00       5.00
```

I have two measures simply summing the TOTSALE and EQSALE

```
SUMTOTSALE = SUM(TOTSALE)
SUMEQSALE = SUM(EQSALE)
```

Now all I want to be able to do is count the clients whose SUMTOTSALE=SUMEQSALE. So in this case I want to return only 1 which would be A. My measure that is not working is this:

```
MEASURE = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(CLIENT),SUMTOTSALE=SUMEQSALE)
```

The measure doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the iterator function `SUMX` to loop across clients looking for matches:

```
MEASURE = SUMX(
 VALUES('Table'[Client]),
 IF([SUMTOTSALE]=[SUMEQSALE],1)
)
```